# Is there any alternative to OrderByDescending() because it's slowing down my query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

```
         query = from q in query
         group q by q.Student.Name
          into qGroup
          orderby qGroup.Key
        select qGroup
        .OrderBy(c => c.Student.RoleId.Value == (int)RoleType.Temp ? 0 : 1)
        .ThenBy(c => c.Student.RoleId.Value == (int)RoleType.Perm ? 0 : 1)
        .ThenBy(s => s.Student.RoleId)
        .FirstOrDefault();

  query = query
           .OrderByDescending(a => a.Student.Date)
           .ThenByDescending(a => a.Student.Id);
        
   var students = query
                    .Skip((model.pageNumber - 1) * model.pageSize)
                    .Take(model.pageSize)
                    .AsQueryable();


   var studentsRet = Mapper.Map<List<Students_Dto>>(students);`
```

the mapping part gets super slower because of

```
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.Student.Date)
  .ThenByDescending(a => a.Student.Id); `
```

What to do?

but if i remove this part; it loads very fast.

Records are around 50k.

I cannot skip this sorting but with this it takes 10s to load.

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project6].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Project6].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
    [Project6].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
    [Project6].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], 
    [Project6].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], 
    [Project6].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Project6].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], 
    [Project6].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], 
    [Project6].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent16].[StudentDate] AS [StudentDate], 
        [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Limit1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
        [Limit1].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
        [Limit1].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], 
        [Limit1].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], 
        [Limit1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
        [Limit1].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], 
        [Limit1].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], 
        [Limit1].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
        FROM    (SELECT 
            [Distinct2].[StudentName] AS [StudentName]
            FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                [Extent7].[StudentName] AS [StudentName]
                FROM     (SELECT [Distinct1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId]
                    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
                        [Extent1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
                        [Extent1].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
                        [Extent1].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], 
                        [Extent1].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], 
                        [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
                        [Extent1].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], 
                        [Extent1].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], 
                        [Extent1].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
                        FROM  [dbo].[Student_State] AS [Extent1]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[StudentId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                        WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[isCurrent]) AND (0 = [Extent2].[isDeleted]) AND (0 = [Extent1].[isDeleated]) AND (6 = [Extent1].[StateId]) AND (([Extent2].[MarkAsImportant] <> 1) OR (([Extent2].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent2].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent2].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Distinct1]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent3] ON [Distinct1].[StudentId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Role] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[RoleId] = [Extent4].[Id]
                    WHERE ([Extent3].[IsArchived] <> 1) AND ([Extent4].[IsArchived] <> 1) ) AS [Filter2]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter2].[StudentId] = [Extent5].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter2].[StudentId] = [Extent6].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent7] ON [Filter2].[StudentId] = [Extent7].[Id]
                WHERE ( (([Extent5].[UserId] IN (N'1249fde4-4881-4c3a-99cd-410af327d7da', N'187862b7-814c-4ee4-ba07-f39e792e3757', N'1abf3481-721b-4f0a-bea1-64714ed07d81', N'1b1fe506-7f40-4b02-9216-114591b1c3c0', N'32a6a152-7d76-4b02-8412-8d4bd425fbd6', N'35970f7a-5315-494b-8cad-16726587abef', N'44e4e56f-7ed0-4e53-b0b5-09da6b7ad0ce', N'5a4b320d-c3f7-4679-8a62-cb9f88eb2f9c', N'7116354c-1f30-4bd5-b987-a3be791f83a2', N'7ffa9388-c9b0-4c83-8914-16d13ac8eaf0', N'897a9326-422d-4564-aeb2-fb4b22da54ef', N'8d6537b9-7bab-4093-88f8-45e1f6703da5', N'8e2cc504-6283-410c-a5b1-9b4e0c089629', N'8fed5f22-77ab-40e5-b418-bfd7d70beaca', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'95b1e864-5819-4d1b-b2cc-42298f73fb50', N'9896fdfc-69fd-46b0-88ce-5ed2a9c86cef', N'a68cdc7f-7b12-446f-8913-0dac98b29b13', N'b66dca4c-4eb3-4f92-9c80-0c4d51bd67aa', N'ca134290-c8f6-449f-a3c3-49604c1dd6d8', N'da93f0a7-2ad4-4842-a6f6-7cef38ca857a', N'dabb07f4-eb28-4a0c-a29e-c7804dbb06e4', N'e07cdeea-5718-4c2e-9700-3a75e9a0d054', N'e3c39a59-a645-4aa4-b7d7-c54880fe282f', N'e7b76fe9-3cc9-470e-b4b3-ddcf98609e87', N'ed7fee89-fae5-4466-abf6-f4d4a6a926c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9')) AND ([Extent5].[UserId] IS NOT NULL))) AND (([Extent6].[IsHidden] <> 1) OR (([Extent6].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent6].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent6].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL)))
            )  AS [Distinct2] ) AS [Project3]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], [Project5].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Project5].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], [Project5].[StateId] AS [StateId], [Project5].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], [Project5].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], [Project5].[Notes] AS [Notes], [Project5].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], [Project5].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], [Project5].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                CASE WHEN (138 = [Extent15].[RoleId]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
                CASE WHEN (141 = [Extent15].[RoleId]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [C2], 
                [Extent15].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
                [Filter5].[Id1] AS [Id], 
                [Filter5].[UserId1] AS [UserId], 
                [Filter5].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
                [Filter5].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
                [Filter5].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], 
                [Filter5].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], 
                [Filter5].[Notes1] AS [Notes], 
                [Filter5].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], 
                [Filter5].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], 
                [Filter5].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
                FROM      (SELECT [Distinct3].[Id] AS [Id1], [Distinct3].[UserId] AS [UserId1], [Distinct3].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], [Distinct3].[StateId] AS [StateId], [Distinct3].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], [Distinct3].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], [Distinct3].[Notes] AS [Notes1], [Distinct3].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], [Distinct3].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], [Distinct3].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
                    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Extent8].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
                        [Extent8].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
                        [Extent8].[StateId] AS [StateId], 
                        [Extent8].[dateTime] AS [dateTime], 
                        [Extent8].[isCurrent] AS [isCurrent], 
                        [Extent8].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
                        [Extent8].[isDeleated] AS [isDeleated], 
                        [Extent8].[RoleOrder] AS [RoleOrder], 
                        [Extent8].[RefuseTo] AS [RefuseTo]
                        FROM  [dbo].[Student_State] AS [Extent8]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[StudentId] = [Extent9].[Id]
                        WHERE (1 = [Extent8].[isCurrent]) AND (0 = [Extent9].[isDeleted]) AND (0 = [Extent8].[isDeleated]) AND (6 = [Extent8].[StateId]) AND (([Extent9].[MarkAsImportant] <> 1) OR (([Extent9].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent9].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent9].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent9].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Distinct3]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent10] ON [Distinct3].[StudentId] = [Extent10].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Role] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[RoleId] = [Extent11].[Id]
                    WHERE ([Extent10].[IsArchived] <> 1) AND ([Extent11].[IsArchived] <> 1) ) AS [Filter5]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent12] ON [Filter5].[StudentId] = [Extent12].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent13] ON [Filter5].[StudentId] = [Extent13].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent14] ON [Filter5].[StudentId] = [Extent14].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent15] ON [Filter5].[StudentId] = [Extent15].[Id]
                WHERE (([Extent13].[IsHidden] <> 1) OR (([Extent13].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent13].[RoleId] IN (124, 138, 140, 141)) AND ([Extent13].[RoleId] IS NOT NULL))) AND ((isCurrent = 1) OR (([Extent12].[UserId] IN (N'1249fde4-4881-4c3a-99cd-410af327d7da', N'187862b7-814c-4ee4-ba07-f39e792e3757', N'1abf3481-721b-4f0a-bea1-64714ed07d81', N'1b1fe506-7f40-4b02-9216-114591b1c3c0', N'32a6a152-7d76-4b02-8412-8d4bd425fbd6', N'35970f7a-5315-494b-8cad-16726587abef', N'44e4e56f-7ed0-4e53-b0b5-09da6b7ad0ce', N'5a4b320d-c3f7-4679-8a62-cb9f88eb2f9c', N'7116354c-1f30-4bd5-b987-a3be791f83a2', N'7ffa9388-c9b0-4c83-8914-16d13ac8eaf0', N'897a9326-422d-4564-aeb2-fb4b22da54ef', N'8d6537b9-7bab-4093-88f8-45e1f6703da5', N'8e2cc504-6283-410c-a5b1-9b4e0c089629', N'8fed5f22-77ab-40e5-b418-bfd7d70beaca', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9', N'95b1e864-5819-4d1b-b2cc-42298f73fb50', N'9896fdfc-69fd-46b0-88ce-5ed2a9c86cef', N'a68cdc7f-7b12-446f-8913-0dac98b29b13', N'b66dca4c-4eb3-4f92-9c80-0c4d51bd67aa', N'ca134290-c8f6-449f-a3c3-49604c1dd6d8', N'da93f0a7-2ad4-4842-a6f6-7cef38ca857a', N'dabb07f4-eb28-4a0c-a29e-c7804dbb06e4', N'e07cdeea-5718-4c2e-9700-3a75e9a0d054', N'e3c39a59-a645-4aa4-b7d7-c54880fe282f', N'e7b76fe9-3cc9-470e-b4b3-ddcf98609e87', N'ed7fee89-fae5-4466-abf6-f4d4a6a926c9', N'9579b2a4-0637-4077-9aae-1c7538b3e3c9')) AND ([Extent12].[UserId] IS NOT NULL))) AND (([Project3].[StudentName] = [Extent14].[StudentName]) OR (([Project3].[StudentName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent14].[StudentName] IS NULL)))
            )  AS [Project5]
            ORDER BY [Project5].[C1] ASC, [Project5].[C2] ASC, [Project5].[RoleId] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent16] ON [Limit1].[StudentId] = [Extent16].[Id]
    )  AS [Project6]
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project6].[StudentDate] DESC, [Project6].[StudentId] DESC)
```

Now this sql takes about same time and even indexes doesn't help.

Note: Names changed for privacy so it's exactly as the actual code but with chnaged table names and all.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Which SQL is generated?

Comment: do you know how to have a look on the generated SQL query?

Comment: You already have `FirstOrDefault()` so something doesn't add up here. Are you sure this is your actual code?

Comment: yes, my actual with just names being changed.\

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv now added. check please

Comment: @MongZhu: just added. please check

Comment: I think, better to write SQL by yourself. It is terrible. You need just Window Function ROW_NUMBER with proper filter. Anyway what is required in `Students_Dto`? Show this class.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on the `Date` column:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_date_desc ON Student(Date DECS)
```

If that doesn't help you could try to create a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_datedesc_id ON Student(Date DECS, Id DESC)
```

Comment: Loved you answer but unfortunately it didn't improve. I tried :(

Comment: any idea on how to improve?

Comment: I tried rebuilding and everything but no prpogress

Comment: @Chattery: try a composite index, edited the answer

Comment: hi, i tried but no improvement :(

Comment: instead it made it more slower

Comment: Indexes won't help in grouping query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: have added the generated sql code. please check

Answer (score 0):

The OrderByDescending() part of your Queryable is translated to that last line:

```
 ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project6].[StudentDate] DESC, [Project6].[StudentId] DESC)
```

which forces the whole thing to be evaluated, before the paging-stuff can be applied.  With the paging and default sort the `ORDER BY ... OVER(...)` is omitted,
and you're probably seeing the optimizer limiting the number of rows before doing all those expensive joins.

As for a solution to your problem: You need to trace back a few steps. Or all of the steps. For instance, what is it that produces the [Project3] and [Project5] parts of the query? [Project3] selects a whole bunch of data, joins [dbo].[Student] 5(!?) times, has a bunch of (redundant) filters .. And ends up outputting DISTINCT(StudentName)

And then everything is repeated in Project5. Except more data is output - could these two parts be combined somehow? Or split into separate queries?

I would go way back, strip the query of filters and joins and add them one after another all the while keeping an eye on the generated SQL. And then in the end, when the produced SQL is lean and mean, you can make it go really fast by applying proper indexes.